# XML data formation using object types

Tags: xml, oracle11g, oracle-objects

I need to generate XML using Oracle object types and element will have attributes. The complication is both element and attribute will have values as below

> employee> ename id=100>Aaron  /ename> /employee>

Requirement is to achieve this with object types only ,not to use xmlelement,xmlattributes since real scenario contains numerous number of columns.

```
Create or replace type ename_type as object("@id" number,ename varchar2(100));
```

Please help to write SQL query

```
Select xmlement("employee",xmlforest()) from employees;
```

Comment: hi man, check this answer bellow.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here it is:

**DDL**:

```
create type ename_type as object  (
  id number,
  ename varchar2(100)
);

create table employees of ename_type;

insert into employees values ( ename_type( 1,'dani') );
```

**DML to generate your XML**:

```
Select XMLELEMENT("employee",
                  XMLATTRIBUTES(e.id AS "ID"),
                  xmlforest(e.name)) 
from employees e;
```

**Explanation**:

on DDL we create the type and a table of objects. Then, on DML, we apply XMLELEMENT function to both, attributes and forest.

**More info**:

You can learn about it on [Database SQL Reference docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions220.htm)

Enjoy!